# What is the difference between a websocket and a socket?

Tags: networking

I understood a socket as a representation of connection to a program, which could be ip address + port, but now i read that a websocket is a network protocol of its own. Is it correct, that only the names sound very similar, but that both are totally different concepts?

Comment: Short answer: Yes. Wikipedia [tells us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) "The **WebSocket protocol** was standardized by the IETF as RFC 6455 in 2011". A **socket**, on the other hand, is not a protocol but an inter-process communication device. See `man 7 socket`: "The BSD compatible sockets are the uniform interface between the user process and the network protocol stacks in the kernel".

Comment: It's probably incorrect to talk about **a** websocket.

Comment: @berndtausch I know i should not do this, but thanks alot. Your explanation really helped!